# How to format and use the extended partition

Tags: partition, hard-disk, ext4, fdisk

The output of `df -h` as below:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           796M  1.7M  794M   1% /run
/dev/sda7        85G  6.2G   74G   8% /
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0      1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/61
/dev/loop2       43M   43M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1313
/dev/loop1      150M  150M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/67
/dev/loop3       89M   89M     0 100% /snap/core/7270
/dev/loop5      4.2M  4.2M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/406
/dev/loop4       15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/296
/dev/loop6       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1066
/dev/loop7      3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/100
/dev/sda1       453M  113M  313M  27% /boot
/dev/sda6       9.4G  993M  7.9G  11% /home
tmpfs           796M   16K  796M   1% /run/user/121
tmpfs           796M     0  796M   0% /run/user/1001
```

So, `/home/` is mounted on `/dev/sad6`, and `/` is mounted on `/dev/sda7`.

As you see, my `/home` is very small.

Then I execute `parted /dev/sda -l` and here is the output:

```
Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 183GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  500MB   499MB   primary   ext4            boot
 2      501MB   107GB   107GB   extended
 5      501MB   4596MB  4095MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
 6      4597MB  14.8GB  10.2GB  logical   ext4
 7      14.8GB  107GB   92.5GB  logical   ext4
```

So, `1` is `/boot`, `6` is `/home`, `7` is `/`.

`2` is large enough, it seems that `5` which is SWAP is used `2` but the size of `5` is only 4095M. There are a large unused space at `2`.

I've tried to format the `2` with the command `mkfs.ext4` but I got an error:

```
mke2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
Found a dos partition table in /dev/sda2
Proceed anyway? (y,N) y
mkfs.ext4: inode_size (128) * inodes_count (0) too big for a
        filesystem with 0 blocks, specify higher inode_ratio (-i)
        or lower inode count (-N).
```

Is this because the `2` contains the `5`? How could I use the `2` as my `/home` directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the output of parted shows that 2 is built up of 5, 6 and 7. Maybe that would be clearer if the start end end adresses of the sectors would not be in human readable form (compare it to the output of `fdisk -l /dev/sda)`.

That means it is no solution to use 2 for your homedirectories, since they are already part of it.

When you setup a new computer or filesystem, consider using lvm, that makes dealing with this kind of problems much easier. Changes to the partitions are easier to implement.